# Is it possible to clip and fill other value with NAN in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, clip

To keep only the positive values, we can clip a dataframe or a specific column(s) of a dataframe using

```
df.clip(lower = 0)
```

But it replaces all negative values with zero. Is it possible to keep only non-negative values and replace all other with `Nan`?

I looked in [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) pandas documentation, but `fill` method is not here.

Another way is to replace all zeros with `Nan` but it will also convert those values which were actually Zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) or [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html):

```
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  2 -6  8
1 -5 -8  0

df1 = df.mask(df.lt(0))
print (df1)
     a   b  c
0  2.0 NaN  8
1  NaN NaN  0
```

---

```
df2 = df.mask(df.le(0))
print (df2)
     a   b    c
0  2.0 NaN  8.0
1  NaN NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Just for future reference, if anyone is looking for the negative values instead of positive, just use `gt` or `ge` instead of `lt` and `le` method.